# -ERR Exceeded the login limit for a 15 minute period. Reduce the frequency of requests to the POP3 server

Tags: c#, email, pop3, hotmail

using following code i have reading msg from my hotmail account . But sometimes the following error coming . `-ERR Exceeded the login limit for a 15 minute period. Reduce the frequency of requests to the POP3 server` . can anyone tell me whats the reason for this ? Is that server problem or anything else ? other than pop3 anyother protocol can we use for hotmail?

```
  public string hotmail(string username, string password)
  {
    string result = "";
    string str = string.Empty;
    string strTemp = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
        tcpclient.Connect("pop3.live.com", 995);
        System.Net.Security.SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream());
        sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop3.live.com");
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sslstream);
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslstream);
        strTemp = reader.ReadLine();
        sw.WriteLine("USER" + " " + username);
        sw.Flush();
        strTemp = reader.ReadLine();
        sw.WriteLine("PASS" + " " + password);
        sw.Flush();
        strTemp = reader.ReadLine();
        string[] numbers = Regex.Split(strTemp, @"\D+");
        int a = 0;
        foreach (string value in numbers)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {

                int i = int.Parse(value);
                numbers[a] = i.ToString();
                a++;
            }
        }
        sw.WriteLine("RETR" + " " + numbers[0]);
        sw.Flush();
        strTemp = reader.ReadLine();
        while ((strTemp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (strTemp == ".")
            {
                break;
            }
            if (strTemp.IndexOf("-ERR") != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            str += strTemp;
        }
        sw.WriteLine("Quit ");
        sw.Flush();
        result = str;
        return result;
     }
     Catch ( Exception ex)
     {}
     return result;
  }
```

thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the mail inbox , you may get mail regarding this and accept it. Otherwise Try to give the request after some time. Because `google` having some restriction to read mail using pop settings.

Answer (score 1):

Any other protocol you can use?  Yes, [hotmail/outlook.com now supports IMAP](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2013/09/12/outlook-com-now-with-imap.aspx).

But the issue with the code here seems to be that you're creating a new `TcpClient` every time you run this.  If you're running it many times in in a row, Outlook.com/Hotmail will eventually complain.  It's as if you've got tons of clients from a single source connecting to their server, which is, when it's not testing code, often a sign of email abuse.

```
TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();  // Hello, new.
tcpclient.Connect("pop3.live.com", 995);
```

If you've got a lot to do on the server, keep a single connection active longer, and close it up when you're done.

Every time you run the code in your question, you're creating (and not `tcpclient.Close()`-ing) a connection to pop3.live.com.  I usually only get this error when I've had a lot of connections that don't close properly due to errors when I'm messing with my code.

MSDN actually has a decent example for [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but you might be more interested in another example from SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252401/1028230).  Check out how it uses `using`, and nests a loop inside.

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect("pop3.live.com", 995);

    while(variableThatRepresentsRunning)
    {
        // talk to POP server
    }
}
```

By the way, **the best advice I can give here is to tell you not to reinvent the wheel** (unless you're just having fun playing with the POP server.  Throwing commands via TCP can be lots of fun, especially with IMAP).

**[OpenPop.NET](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/) is a great library to handle POP requests in C#**, includes [a good MIME parser](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleSpecificParts.php), and, if you're still working on this, should speed you along quite a bit. Its [examples page](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/examples.php) is excellent.